# studio.sh is not working on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-17.04

i have a problem in running ./studio.sh and when I try to run it by terminal , this error shows in the picture attached

[image: Command not found]
[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL4eX.png)

Comment: I think that you need to give more context of your problem

Comment: can you paste the path to your .studio.sh here?

Comment: Did my solution work ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to to into the directory where your **studio.sh** file exists as below :

```
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

I am using path to android studio in my system, You need to your system's path to android studio, where your android studio is located.